# Set field to be valid in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I have a Vue JS form using Vee Validate, I have a method set up where I'd like to make a particular input field valid whenever the method runs. The method runs after a button is pressed:

```
/**
         * Use email suggestion
         */
        setEmailSuggestion: function preventScreenAutoLock(suggestion) {
          this.formData.AppEmail = this.formData.AppEmail + suggestion
        }
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing this, I essentially need to remove the validation error classes, and set them to be valid

Comment: This should be done either on field input or blur (when you lose focus on it) or on submit of whole form.

Comment: That method runs when a button is pressed, so the user wouldn't actually be on the field.

Comment: WIthout more code it’ll be difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you really want without more code. However, you can clear errors from the `ErrorBag` manually: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/errorbag.html#errorbag

And you can also use either `reset` or `detach` on that field: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/validator.html#api

Why `detach`? Well, if you don't care about the result of those validation rules after hitting this method, why keep it attached? You can `extend` again later if you want. Again, it's hard to say what you are looking for here.